# RestSharp isn't consistent when calling wordpress/woocomerce site

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, restsharp

In my dev environment, I have a wordpress/woocommerce site locally all hosted under IIS.

Using the following code restsharp works:

```
var fullEndPoint = string.Concat(site, "/wp-json/wc/v3/", endpoint)
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(fullEndPoint)
{
       Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(consumerkey, woosecret, "", "")
};
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddJsonBody(serializedData);
client.Execute(request);
```

When I change the fullEndPoint, consumerkey and woosecret to be our main test site which mirrors our live site (running on apache/linux), I receive

> Sorry you are not allowed to create Resource.

If I post to our test site the same data using postman, it goes through and works.

For the purposes of testing, if I then change the above declaration of client to be:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://wordpress.mytestsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_a24ad9ddea2d9fe71d9172c415fd51b4dc83a6dc&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1627038994&oauth_nonce=T9gfeZGdmNx&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=OJB1TBpLpA%2Bet0A%2FDFbozOT9nf8%3D");
```

where fullendpoint is the code shown in postman's code windows for Restsharp, again the code works, so I know the error is misleading. So Why doesn't restsharp work in the initial way for me when I point to my test site?

Edit:

If I change client such that I'm now setting it up as:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(fullEndPoint)
{
    Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForClientAuthentication(consumerkey, woosecret, username, password)
};
```

where username and password equal the user set up in woo commerce against the consumer key for read/write access, I still receive an access denied error

Comment: Which endpoint are you really calling? Use Fiddler or any other debugging proxy to see which URL is really called and what settings are used. Postman can tell you only whether a specific HTTP call works, not what requests are made by other applications. And OAuth isn't basic authentication. It's not enough to use the correct credentials to get a token, the site must accept that token and trust the token's provider.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes but as I said in my second part, pasting the code directly from postman will post my data into the woo site, so I must be hitting the correct end point

Comment: You *assume* you do. Don't you actually want to see what's going on? What is different in the two calls? What headers are different? Perhaps the token is different?

Comment: Besides, you're using `OAuth1Authenticator` but never pass any token. This shouldn't work unless the site that "works" does so by ignoring authentication.